# Rails: where is the natural place to add methods to standard library class like DateTime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need to check a `DateTime` object is at specific date. Actually, date of `Dec 31 9999` which is used as an infinity value in one of our legacy system data.

Comparing year with 9999, like `some_date.year == 9999` is just enough to do this, but I don't like this to sprinkle everywhere.

I usually try to avoid monkey-patching, but in this case, it looks like clearer.

Now, where is the natural place to define such a patch in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you'd put such a patch under `lib/` and require it from an initializer.

Comment: Thanks. That's sounds natural.